# Pydev Program Continually Terminating

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I am fairly new programmer, currently I have been assigned a project to create a looping calculator that even after you use one of the calculator functions it will keep going until you make a selection provided. My problem with my calculator currently is that there is an incessant termination whenever I try to test my function on Pydev. I already fixed the first problem where Pydev read one of my variables (choice) as unused so I used the "ctrl + 1" trick and that got rid of the unused variable warning. Any tips on how I might be able to run this program and have it continually loop?

```
def main():      
    loop=1
    choice=0  # @UnusedVariable
    while loop == 1:
        print("Welcome to Calculator Function!")
        print("Your options are:")
        print(" ")
        print("1/) Addition")
        print("2/) Subtraction") 
        print("3/) Multiplication")
        print("4/) Division")
        print("5/) Quit CalculatorFunction.py")
        print(" ")

    choice = int(raw_input("Choose your option: ").strip())
    if choice == 1:
        add1 = input("Add what: ")
        add2 = input("To what: ")
        print add1, "+", add2, "=", add1+add2
    elif choice == 2:
        sub2 = input("Subtract what: ")
        sub1 = input("From what: ")
        print sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1-sub2
    elif choice == 3:
        mult1 = input("Multiply what: ")
        mult2 = input("To what: ")
        print mult1, "*", mult2, "=", mult1*mult2
    elif choice == 4:
        div2= input("Divide what: ")
        div1= input("From what: ")
        print div1, "/", div2, "=", div1/div2
    elif choice == 5:
        loop = 0
        print"Thank you for using CalculatorFunction.py have a good day!" 
    else:
        print"No selection made, please try again."    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: *"incessant termination"*?! I'd say it would never terminate; `loop == 1` remains `True` indefinitely.

Comment: It looks like what you want is a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (read-eval-print loop). Currently, the most obvious issue I can see would be that you have nothing except printing going on in the `while` loop. If you copied the indenting correctly, the while loop should run forever, printing nothing but the prompt.

Comment: Also, you are (kind of dangerously) mixing `input` and `raw_input`. If you're using an early enough version of python that `raw_input` is an option, chances are pretty good you should **never** use `input`. There are, of course, corner cases that would make your life way easier with no particular downside, but those are very, very rare and a good rule of thumb is to pretend they don't exist until you're more knowledgeable.

Comment: So, all of those `input` calls should be calls to `raw_input`.

Comment: I want it to continue to loop unless the user inputs the last choice in which case the program would terminate itself @jonrsharpe

Comment: Yes, so *what is happening instead*? Your problem description doesn't match the code; edit the question accordingly. Try cutting your code down to a [minimal example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: So I must correct my indentation and switch around the input into raw_input. I am using python version 2.7 so raw_input works, but I understand what you are saying when it comes to switching that around @ParthianShot

Comment: The problem is that the program terminates itself without allowing a user to input anything or in other words my program does not even run. @jonrsharpe

Comment: When I copy paste that code, I get what I expected; the code does run, but the first set of `print`s loops indefinitely. Please review your question as requested.

Comment: Are you using pydev? Because it doesn't run at all, it just immediately goes to terminated. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Nope, not using PyDev, just running your code. You need to rethink the indentation; your loop scope currently doesn't make sense. Try waking through it line by line and remember indentation = scope in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if - else` block is outside the while loop, that is why it doesn't work. Here's the properly indented code:

```
def main():      
    loop=1
    choice=0  # @UnusedVariable
    while loop == 1:
        print("Welcome to Calculator Function!")
        print("Your options are:")
        print(" ")
        print("1/) Addition")
        print("2/) Subtraction") 
        print("3/) Multiplication")
        print("4/) Division")
        print("5/) Quit CalculatorFunction.py")
        print(" ")

        choice = int(raw_input("Choose your option: ").strip())
        if choice == 1:
            add1 = input("Add what: ")
            add2 = input("To what: ")
            print add1, "+", add2, "=", add1+add2
        elif choice == 2:
            sub2 = input("Subtract what: ")
            sub1 = input("From what: ")
            print sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1-sub2
        elif choice == 3:
            mult1 = input("Multiply what: ")
            mult2 = input("To what: ")
            print mult1, "*", mult2, "=", mult1*mult2
        elif choice == 4:
            div2= input("Divide what: ")
            div1= input("From what: ")
            print div1, "/", div2, "=", div1/div2
        elif choice == 5:
            loop = 0
            print"Thank you for using CalculatorFunction.py have a good day!" 
        else:
            print"No selection made, please try again."    



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This worked well on pydev.

Comment: Thanks, I had fixed it earlier but it seems this one took less work than the one I just previously made.

Comment: You should try out the debugger in eclipse. As a new programmer, debugging is an extremely useful skill to learn.

Comment: I was looking that up today actually! I still have a lot to learn, I'm going to edit the program again so that the user will be asked how many functions they want to do, and the program will terminate after they perform that amount of functions with the calculator. @user2963623

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your tips on "indentation" and a couple of other things I finally figured out the program works thank you all for your input. What I did to fix my immediate termination was fix the indentation. Then to make it so the program continually loops if a selection isn't made I added the continue, in essence the only way to terminate the program is to select the option quit which is listed as "5".

```
def main()
    loop=1
    choice=0  # @UnusedVariable
    while loop == 1:
        print(" ")
        print("Welcome to Calculator Function!")
        print("Your options are:")
        print(" ")
        print("1) Addition")
        print("2) Subtraction") 
        print("3) Multiplication")
        print("4) Division")
        print("5) Quit CalculatorFunction.py")
        print(" ")

        choice = int(raw_input("Choose your option: ").strip())
        if choice == 1:
            add1 = int(raw_input("Add what: "))
            add2 = int(raw_input("To what: "))
            print add1, "+", add2, "=", add1+add2
        elif choice == 2:
            sub2 = int(raw_input("Subtract what: "))
            sub1 = int(raw_input("From what: "))
            print sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1-sub2
        elif choice == 3:
            mult1 = int(raw_input("Multiply what: "))
            mult2 = int(raw_input("To what: "))
            print mult1, "*", mult2, "=", mult1*mult2
        elif choice == 4:
            div2= int(raw_input("Divide what: "))
            div1= int(raw_input("From what: "))
            print div1, "/", div2, "=", div1/div2
        elif choice == 5:
            loop = 0 #Ends the program
            print"Thank you for using CalculatorFunction.py have a good day!" 
        else:
            print"No selection made, please try again."
            continue #loops the program
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()